Can I use 15amp inlet and outlets with 12 gauge wire?
I am installing a 15A flanged inlet on the outside of my shed to get power there when I need it, but my whole house is wire with 12 gauge wire.
I want to put a few outlets around the shed for tools and such but just want to make sure I don't burn the shed down.

@isherwood   OP is asking about an inlet.  I know outlets are okay for 20 amps, not sure if inlets are the same, especially since they are single.

Fair enough, but we still don't know what breaker's protecting the circuit. That's critical information.

+1 for what Isherwood commented. If the inlet is connected to a circuit with a 20A breaker, there will be 20A on the circuit (and it will require 12ga wire). While there are different plug/socket configurations for 15A and 20A, most "standard" outlets will accept a "standard" (NEMA 5-15) plug even though they are wired to a 20A circuit.

Well, your 15A outlet is only going to draw 15A max, because you can't plug an actual 20A device into it.

So you have a 15A inlet? connect that to a 15A breaker and then to the rest of the wiring,  there's no prohibition on using 12GA on 15A outlets.
But perhaps you should consider doing it all in 20A instead,  you'll need a fatter extension lead to feed the shed, but you will avoid the risk posed by easily available undersized extension leads and your shed will have better power.

Good suggestion, but I'd be careful assuming that a future person would use a true 20A extension cord, as it's hard to find a true 20A, and even a lot of the longer extension cords aren't rated for even a full 15A.  And then, you'd need a 20A inlet connector, which is probably a lot harder to find.

@Milwrdfan -- it took me about ten seconds to find a 20 A inlet on Amazon. Same for a 20 A extension cord.

@PeteBecker Except that you have to be careful on Amazon - some of the stuff is legitimate UL/ETL listed product from reliable manufacturers. A lot of it is not.
